# When i change my orientation from portrait to landscape it replays the splash screen

Tags: android, orientation, android-orientation

When i change my orientation from portrait to landscape it replays the splash screen, then loads my weburl. But is there a way to just let it continue where it was, so it doesn't replay the whole process? I have tried "android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize", but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: did you try **screenLayout** `android:configChanges="orientation|screenLayout|screenSize"` ?

Comment: Hi Fresh Prince, you'd need to share your code. Rotation will cause the layout to refresh and as long as your 'views' have IDs associated with them, they should repopulate in general. If your splash screen is being shown when you rotate then I wonder if there is something in your 'onCreate' method that is causing this.

Without sharing code, however, it is hard to help you.

Comment: @greysqrl , i only made one activity which includes the splash screen and a webview i did this so i can load the webview in the background till the animation stops here is the [code](http://pastebin.com/8sEh11dr)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your code

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration config) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(config);
}
```

Edit :Add this code.

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle bundle) {

    webview.saveState(bundle);


}
```

And in onCreate of Activity class add -

```
if (savedInstanceState != null)
        webview.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
else{
    webview.loadUrl("url");
}
```

Comment: No errors nothing happened same problem i added a comment underneath my post with the code of the activity.

Comment: @FreshPrince See my edited answer and try this.
It worked for me.
Let me know if it works for you?

Comment: I just tried your code this is my whole java file: [code](http://pastebin.com/cPfVdCMa)

Comment: i got it to not replay my splash screen but it doesnt keep the page going it reloads back to the main page.